# How to parametrize a function with inherited types in Scala

Tags: scala, compilation

Let us say that I have those classes defined (this is a simplified version of my code)

```
sealed trait Expression

trait ExpressionA extends Expression
trait ExpressionB extends Expression

case class OperationA(op: String, a: ExpressionA, b:ExpressionA) extends ExpressionA
case class OperationB(op: String, a: ExpressionB, b:ExpressionB) extends ExpressionB
case class ComparisonB(op: String, a: ExpressionA, b:ExpressionA) extends ExpressionB
case class VariableA(op: String, a: ExpressionA) extends ExpressionA
```

I want then to replace a given string in the VariableA class
so I can write

```
def replace(exp: ExpressionB, operation: String => String): ExpressionB = exp match {
  case ComparisonB(op, a, b) => ComparisonB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
  case OperationB(op, a, b) => OperationB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))

}

def replace(exp: ExpressionA, operation: String => String): ExpressionA = exp match {
  case OperationA(op, a, b) => OperationA(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
  case VariableA(name) => VariableA(operation(name))
}
```

But i'd like to merge those two functions in one, with a generic types.

Here is what i have tried

```
def replace[T <: Expression](exp:T, operation: String => String):T = exp match {
  case ComparisonB(op, a, b) => ComparisonB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
  case OperationB(op, a, b) => OperationB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
  case OperationA(op, a, b) => OperationA(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
  case VariableA(name) => VariableA(operation(name))
}
```

I get the error

```
Expression of type ExpressionA does not conform to expected type T
```

Despite it is theoretically always of the same type as the input. So I don't know what is wrong with my code, is it missing some implicits, or the wrong way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want return type of `replace` to depend on value of `exp` (namely on whether `exp` matches a particular pattern) then actually you want a [polymorphic](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) function.

```
  trait Replacer[T <: Expression] {
    def replace(exp: T, operation: String => String): T
  }

  object Replacer {
    implicit val exprA: Replacer[ExpressionA] =
      (exp: ExpressionA, operation: String => String) => exp match {
        case OperationA(op, a, b) => OperationA(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
        case VariableA(name) => VariableA(operation(name))
      }

    implicit val exprB: Replacer[ExpressionB] =
      (exp: ExpressionB, operation: String => String) => exp match {
        case ComparisonB(op, a, b) => ComparisonB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
        case OperationB(op, a, b) => OperationB(op, replace(a, operation), replace(b, operation))
      }
  }

  def replace[T <: Expression](exp: T, operation: String => String)(implicit replacer: Replacer[T]): T =
    replacer.replace(exp, operation)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala `match` expression returns a common type for all cases. In the example you've provided that common type is `Expression` not `T` thus you get compiler error.

You can either define your return type as `Expression` or (if you want to preserve the type passed to method define replace as an instance method of `Expression` namely def `replace(operation: String => String): Expression` and override it in case classes replacing the return type e.g. `def replace(operation: String => String): OperationA`